# Do we need to join in the controller or model when you use SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In MVC frameworks, where do you usually embed SQL Alchemy Code, is it ideal to put the query in `Controller Methods` or just use the `Model Methods`?

```
query = session.query(User, Document, DocumentsPermissions).join(Document).join(DocumentsPermissions).filter_by(Document.name=="Something")
```

Or I just delegate this to a Model Method which takes a args? What is the preferred way to do this? One of the benefits of the latter is that it can be re-used and it almost presents a view for the API programmers. Another advantage is that I can easily over-ride this if I make it a class method. This is usually helpful in customizations especially in commercial softwares.

```
#Ctrl.py
self.getdocument("Foo")

#Mdl.py
def getdocument(name):
    query = session.query(User, Document, DocumentsPermissions).join(Document).join(DocumentsPermissions).filter_by(Document.name=="Something")
```

**TL;DR**: Isn't the concept of "M" in MVC blurred when you use ORM's like SQL Alchemy? I didn't have any problems with `Model` `View` `Controller` design patterns.

[PS: I am not sure if this belongs to Code Review Site, if so please let me know, I can just transfer over.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly prefer the second approach. It has a few advantages:

- Your controller code can be dumb. This is good. Controllers that just fetch data from the backend, possibly reformat it a little bit, and pass it on to views are very easy to reason about.
- It's easier to test that method in isolation. You can run `getdocument('valid_name')`, `getdocument(None)`, `getdocument(123)`, etc. to ensure they all work or fail as expected without dealing with all the surrounding controller code.
- It's easier to test the controller. You can write a mock for `getdocument()` so that it always returns a known value and test that your controller processes it correctly.

Comment: I didn't think about Testing, that always an advantage with de-coupling.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to put database query code in the Controller rather than the Model. As my understanding goes, Model methods are used to transform the data of the model into something else.

For example, a `UserModel` may have a `FullName()` method to return the concatenation of the user's first and last names.

Whereas, a `UserController` contains a `GetAll()` method to get a list of all users, which is where the database query code is found.

Comment: Its nice for small queries, but it can become really problematic if you are repeating your queries over and over which is really common in web applications. Imagine you want to customize something.

Comment: @Nishant True. Though you could always abstract out the most common queries into a parent controller and inherit it as needed.

Comment: I guess thats what Model is, atleast in my example :-) Its nothing but Python methods that only do the SQL fetch nothing else. Is that what you are telling? If so the "Model" I am talking about is the same, except I am also thinking of parametrizing it so its also re-usable. Ao abstract, parametric and let many others consume it as well.

Comment: @Nishant Ah, I see. Yea, the semantics between models and controllers can get confusing. I have used parent controller classes with parameterized methods before, so, your thoughts are not wrong. Controllers are meant to be a help, not a hindrance, so mold them however works best for you.